# how to upload photo

Tags: php, facebook, upload, photo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload image with facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518194/upload-image-with-facebook-api)

Can someone tell me how to upload photo to facebook api. upload diferent photos. I try many of codes , they works but facebook restriced apps, I want codes that facebook don't restriced them.Help me, some apps thats work always .. 1. http://www.facebook.com/pages/Fu%C3%9Fballfieber/248155528600196?sk=app_155808804537600 2.    http://www.facebook.com/pages/Wundervoll/179034668874524?sk=app_282756095126852

Comment: can you be more specific please? what platform you use? which SDK? have you setup an application already?

Comment: I have an app now , but facebook restriced it, I only want to know what I'm doing wrong that facebook restriced my app.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are trying to acchive here but everything you need should be in the dev section for facebook. Try reading this page https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/